# How do I convert an Enty in tkinter into a string or an integer in Python

Tags: python

I keep trying to convert an entry and it keeps saying

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Entry'
```

Here is part of my program:

```
self.answers = Entry(self)
self.answers.grid(row = 5, column = 3, sticky = W)

def update_text(self):
    answers = self.answers
    answer = int(answers)
    if self.answer > the_number:
        answer =("Lower...")
    else:
        answer =("Higher...")
    tries += 1
```

I tried 
    value = answers.get()
and now its says

```
NameError: global name 'answers' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to show *where* you tried `answers.get()`... In my answer, I was assuming you would put it after the line `answers = self.answers`.  Is that where you put it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [get](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method) the entry's value:

```
value = answers.get()
```

This should return whatever string happens to be in the entry field when it is called.